# Proper method for Locking Classes and Properties when threading applications in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, coding-style

I am asking for coding convention and the proper method for using a lock mechanism on properties and methods with in a class.

So for example I have two properties and two methods:

```
public class FOO
{
private Guid uniqueIdentifier;
object _syncuniqueIdentifier = new object();
public Guid UniqueIdentifier 
{
       get 
       { 
        lock(_syncuniqueIdentifier)
        {
        return uniqueIdentifier;
        }        
    }
    set 
    { 
         lock(_syncuniqueIdentifier)
         {  
        uniqueIdentifier = value;
         }          
    }
}

private string userName;
object _syncuserName = new object();
public string UserName 
{
       get 
       { 
        lock(_syncuserName)
        {
        return userName;
        }        
    }
    set 
    { 
         lock(_syncuserName)
         {  
        userName = value;
         }          
    }
}

object _syncMyMethod = new object();
public void myMethod(object argument1, object argument2)
{
   lock(_syncMyMethod)
   {
   do work with argument1 and argument2
   }
}


}
```

Am I using the correct pattern to implement threading or should I instead put a single object _syncLock and have all properties and methods lock on that object ?
What is the coding standard for doing this ?

Comment: Without knowing what is actually being done here, how the object is being used, what types of changes are safe/appropriate, there's no way for us to state whether or not this is acceptable.

Comment: One lock to rule them all.  The way you have it, there's nothing to prevent some thread from modifying the properties in the middle of the method.

Comment: Quite frankly, there is no coding standard for threading, there's just correctness of behavior. If your current scenario fits the bill, it's okay, but without knowing the implementation details, nobody can tell if you need one, two, three or, perhaps, no locks at all.

Comment: The odds that this kind of fine-grained locking is correct are exceedingly low.  There is for example no guarantee whatsoever that client code can obtain the correct UniqueIdentifier for a specific UserName.  You cannot guess how client code is going to use this object, it must be that client code that uses locks.  Having to pass the job of implementing thread-safety to a programmer that's least qualified to get it correct is one of the core reasons why writing thread-safe code is so difficult.

Comment: Since I only know enough to know that I need to lock when multithreading applications in order to prevent cross threads and some other unintended nasty behavior , synchronizing flow and so forth - it is hard for me to articulate if my current scenario fits the bill. I wish I knew more to state things better.

Comment: @theB. Thanks for pointing that out! I was looking at the lock and thinking they are locked and can't be changed - but you are right unless the class is locked in its entirety (not sure on how to do that except outside on the instance) or those properties are private they can be changed outside the class level.

Comment: @Hans very good points - I am a prime example of why it is hard and your points follow along with the theB's comments.

Comment: Just use a single `object` for all the things that are logically grouped (in this case you'd use the same `object` in all 3 locks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are using valid pattern assuming fields are independent and frequently changed. Using single lock object is reasonable option too as long as there is not much computation happening under lock.

If two (or more) fields are dependent locking at property level will not work (even with single object for locking) and you should either lock outside of properties or restructure API to prevent modification of just one property.

Callers to take care of locking:

```
// no locks here, all callers to lock
public class FOO {
   public Guid UniqueIdentifier {get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}
}

// in caller code
usersLock = new object();
List<FOO> users = ...

lock(usersLock) 
{
    // modify/read users here.
    ...
}
```

alternative API:

```
public class FOO {
  private object idLock = new Object();

  // immutable Id class
  public class Id {
   public Id(....){...}
   public Guid UniqueIdentifier {get; private set;}
   public string UserName {get; private set;}
  }

  private Id id;
  public Id { get {lock(idLock){ return id;}}
              set {lock(idLock){ id = value;}}
}
```

Note that based on field names in the sample (`UniqueIdentifier` and `UserName`) this fields come together and locking on field level will only provide thread safety in sense of "no exceptions", but it is trivial to get two out of sync with each other - so one of approaches outlined above likely need to be used instead.